# Ruby: разобрать строку в хэш

Tags: ruby

у меня есть строка, которая содержит:

```
Product Name        : 1 year technical support  - Win forms + Web forms Edition - Single
Product ID          : 40133
Order ID            : 469224-001-1UF
Order Date          : 5/12/2001 7:44 AM
Quantity            : 1
Backup CD           : No
Download Warranty   : No
Coupon used         : 
Currency            : USD
Unit Price          : 10.00 USD
Unit Discount       : 
Volume Discount     : 
Total Discount      : 
Total Product Price : 10.00 USD
```

Нужно каждую строку занести в хеш, при этом значение до двоеточий должно быть ключом

Comment: Ничего, что в ней нет ни одной запятой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берём итератор по отдельным строчкам (чтобы не хранить весь разбитый массив в памяти целиком, а брать подстрочки по одной; это чаще экономия на спичках, но может неплохо сказаться на огромном наборе данных):

```
str.each_line
```

И каждую строчку пробуем засунуть в пустой хэш...

```
   .each_with_object({}) do |line, hash|
```

...следующим образом:

Достаём из строчки ключ и значение (отстригая пробелы: по-моему, это здесь полезно):

```
     key, value = line.split(':', 2) # Разбить по двоеточию не более чем на 2 части
                      .map(&:strip)  # Подстричь оба от пробельных символов
     # Ура декомпозиции!
     # `a, b = [1, 2]` то же, что и `a = 1; b = 2`
```

И если `value` нашлось (не `nil`, что может быть для строк без `:`), запихиваем его в наш хэш:

```
     hash[key] = value unless value.nil?
```

Всё, конец.

```
   end
```

Возвращаемым значением будет искомый хэшмап.

Конечно, это же Ruby, и можно сделать много разных вариаций на тему. Скажем, если вы хотите сделать какой-то постпроцессинг значению, то вместо того, чтобы заворачивать большую часть блока в `unless value.nil?`, можно сделать `next if value.nil?`, и остаток блока будет в случае ненайденного значения просто пропущен.

Answer (score 0):

Вариация на тему :)

```
$str = <<-EOT
Product Name        : 1 year technical support  - Win forms + Web forms Edition - Single
Product ID          : 40192
Order ID            : 469074-001-1UF
Order Date          : 5/12/2011 7:44 AM
Quantity            : 1
Backup CD           : No
Download Warranty   : No
Coupon used         : 
Currency            : USD
Unit Price          : 109.00 USD
Unit Discount       : 
Volume Discount     : 
Total Discount      : 
Total Product Price : 109.00 USD
EOT

$out = Hash.new()

# Собираем хэш (немножко упростилось) :)

$str.each_line do |x|  
  $out[$m[1]] = $m[2] if $m = (/^\s*([^:]*?)\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*$/).match(x) 
end

# Печатаем хэш

$out.each do |key, value|
  puts key + ' : ' + value
end
```

Comment: Ничо так, да. Правда, `.strip` можно учесть в регулярке и убрать. И я ещё обрабатываю пустые строки (были в первой редакции вопроса), ваша реализация на них может, эм, упасть, не найдя `.strip` у `nil`. Но да, в последней редакции вопроса их и правда нет. И да, можно заметить, что я не очень люблю регулярки :)

Comment: Стрип в текущей постановке задачи не получается в регулярку всунуть. Странно руби работает - если значение после ":" пустое, то руби заполняет только два матча, а Перл заполняет три, где второй - заполняет пустой строкой. Ну или я чет не понял. Поэтому захватываю пробелы, чтоб потом их чистить.

Comment: "Я знаю, я воспользуюсь регулярными выражениями!" "Теперь у вас две проблемы..." :D Почему там три группы захвата, кстати, а не две? И чего не заанкерили регулярку на начало и конец строки?

Comment: смысл анкерить, если постоянно откусываю хвост и его в цикле дальше парсю - в конце жадный поиск для хвоста

Comment: стоп .... да, надо 3-ю группу захвата убирать - со старой версии с while еще осталось, щя переделаю

Comment: еще короче получилось)